# Nagios Remote Web Interface Installation

Tags: nagios

I currently have a Nagios monitoring solution installed on one of our App Servers in our DEV environment, and I'd like this solution to monitor all other other App servers in this network (3 in total). We also have a separate Web server, and I'm having difficulty configuring the web interface on this remote server.

All the research I have done so far has given example of a co-hosted Web and App server. Nothign seems to tell me what steps should be followed in order to configure the web interface remotely.

FYI, the App servers are Unix, and Web has Apache insalled on it.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thansk,

Answer (score 2):

The nagios webinterface needs access to the status.dat, so it has to be on the same machine as nagios. However, you could, as already suggested, have a look at the [Thruk](http://thruk.org) interface which supports remote installations through a livestatus connection.

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Thruk](http://www.thruk.org/) Nagios web interface

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be possible to configure web interface on the same server where nagios is and then create a virtual host in apache and point the right ip-address to it in your domain configuration file.